# ¿Las Respuestas con muchos comentarios se deben Reportar?

Tags: soporte, respuesta, comentarios

He leído una respuesta que al parecer no es valida :

[error al ejecutar ng serve --open](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129911/28035)

He notado la cantidad de comentarios que tiene esta respuesta, y pense en reportarla, ya que los comentarios mas que comentarios parecen chat , tambien pense en darle su **-1** pero me dio la duda.

En el sitio para respuestas de este tipo cual son los pasos que deberiamos seguir? para ambos casos *respuestas valida o invalida*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Independientemente de que la respuesta sea válida o no, puedes reportarla para llamar la atención a los moderadores si tiene muchos comentarios o si la conversación se extiende y se separa del tema en cuestión (algo que suele ocurrir cuando hay muchos comentarios).

...Pero no es siempre necesario: los moderadores reciben notificaciones automáticas cuando una publicación (pregunta o respuesta) tiene demasiados comentarios. Cuando se alcanzan los 20 comentarios, recibimos un enlace a la publicación y una notificación como la siguiente:

[image: notificación demasiados comentarios... con dos días de retraso]

Entonces revisamos la conversación, valoramos si los comentarios son necesarios para la publicación o si se deben mover a un chat (y así quitar ruido) y realizamos la acción que se considere más oportuna.

---

Sobre el -1, eso debería depender más de la calidad de la publicación que del número de comentarios publicados en la misma. Otra cosa sería que la respuesta no tenga sentido sin los comentarios, en cuyo caso, habría que pedirle al usuario que edite su publicación.

Puedes encontrar más información sobre ese tema en el centro de ayuda, en los artículos sobre votar [positivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) y [negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).