# Solicitar más información en la pregunta no es un chat

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

A veces me encuentro preguntas mal hechas, el usuario pone lo que tiene de código y solicita una serie de cambios. En muchos de estos casos, el usuario suele ser nuevo, y al pedírsele más información responde, con lo cual veo que ha intentado cosas, y me hace suponer que inicialmente no pone todo para no hacer la pregunta muy pesada o larga de leer, para que llame más la atención.

Sin embargo, a pesar de lo anterior hay que pedirle al usuario comentario a comentario lo que le falta, parte del código generalmente, qué ha intentado, etc... Con lo cual la pregunta acaba con un excesivo número de comentarios, útiles todos, pero demasiados. Hay alguna manera de reducir el número de comentarios una vez que se han aplicado los cambios que no sea ir uno a uno? se puede automatizar esto de alguna manera para que el usuario inicial elimine el comentario directamente si ha añadido lo solicitado?

Comment: Veo muy difícil que se pueda automatizar algo de esto. Siempre, hay que pedir al AP (Autor de la pregunta) que cualquier dato o aclaración lo agregué al cuerpo de su pregunta y no como comentario, en otros casos y con cuidado, se le puede ayudar editando su pregunta para agregar esta información.

Comment: Si los comentarios ya cumplieron su objetivo entonces son innecesarios por lo que para eliminarlos deberias levantar una bandera(icono de bandera al lado izquierdo del comentario) con la opcion "Ya no es neccesario" y nuestros moderadores diamantados haran la magia.

Comment: No pueden borrar sus propios comentarios??? sean buenitos con nosotros!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como miembros de la comunidad debemos escribir la información necesaria para que nos puedan apoyar a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, lo cual se especifica en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help):

[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Cuando otros usuarios requieren información, el OP deberá preferentemente editar su pregunta para actualizarla con más información, se entiende que la pregunta debe estar realizada de acuerdo a lo especificado en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), por lo cual generalmente no debería de existir una gran cantidad de comentarios ya que si sucede esto,  los moderadores reciben una alerta y estos comentarios proceden a ser evaluados para ser enviados a un chat, no de forma automática por lo tanto es otra tarea más para el moderador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Si los comentarios son en verdad útiles y la conversación se extiende, se debe considerar continuar la conversación en un chat, si no es así o se agrega esa información útil también a nuestra pregunta, lo mejor es eliminarlos nosotros mismos.**

---

Por lo tanto contestando a tus preguntas:

> Hay alguna manera de reducir el número de comentarios una vez que se
>   han aplicado los cambios que no sea ir uno a uno?
>   se puede automatizar esto de alguna manera para que el usuario inicial
>   elimine el comentario directamente si ha añadido lo solicitado?

No está automatizado. Es importante como usuarios realizar esta tarea nosotros mismos, ya que si actualizamos la información en nuestra pregunta, debemos considerar eliminar los comentarios ya que ahora podrían considerarse no necesarios.

Revisa esta respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro relacionada a los comentarios:
[¿Las Respuestas con muchos comentarios se deben Reportar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3026/las-respuestas-con-muchos-comentarios-se-deben-reportar/3027#3027)